# Force 'Yes' to all questions when installing R Packages using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Is it possible to install packages (specifically through rpy2) while automatically answering 'Yes' to any interactive questions that may be asked during the install?

This is the code I'm using right now to install, which installs successfully but asks questions that I have to interactively answer:

```
import rpy2.interactive as r
import rpy2.interactive.packages # this can take few seconds
rlib = r.packages.packages
r.packages.importr("utils")
rlib.utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)
rlib.utils.install_packages('my_package')
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you refer to questions related to installing packages in a personal library such as below ?

```
Warning in install.packages("foo") :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Would you like to use a personal library instead?  (y/n) y
```

If so, the location of the install should be specified in the paramater `lib` (and this should keep the function quiet).